# ACF count gallery images

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to make an grid of different size images using the ACF gallery field.

I have managed to do this before in a repeater field by counting rows, but have unable to adjust this to work with the gallery field.

My aim is to have a grid of 10 images using 2 different image sizes.

- Images 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 would be one size
- Images 4, 5, 9, 10 would be a different size

My current markup is:

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('home-image-grid');
    $size = 'full';
    if( $images ): 
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image['ID'], $size ); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried the markup I used previously with a repeater field, but this only outputs image 1.

```
<?php 
    $i = 1;
    $images = get_field('home-image-grid');
    $size = 'full';
    if( $images ): 
?>

    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

        <?php if ( $i == 1 ) { ?>
            image 1
        <?php } elseif ( $i == 2 ) { ?>
            image 2
        <?php } elseif ( $i == 3 ) { ?>
            image 3
        <?php } elseif ( $i == 4 ) { ?>
            image 4
        <?php } ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I presume this is because of the foreach statement. How can I get this to work?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the full code you've posted, but surely you should be incrementing $i with $i++ before the endforeach? At the moment, in your loop, $i is always equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work will be done in both gallery or repeater field, both return the array.

you just forgot to add iteration `$i++` in the loop.

So your loop will be like

```
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

    <?php if ( $i == 1 ) { ?>
        image 1
    <?php } elseif ( $i == 2 ) { ?>
        image 2
    <?php } elseif ( $i == 3 ) { ?>
        image 3
    <?php } elseif ( $i == 4 ) { ?>
        image 4
    <?php } 
     $i++;
     endforeach; ?>
```

also, if you don't have any complicated condition with your array indexes then you can use foreach loop with the array index like

```
<?php foreach( $images as $index => $image ): ?>

    <?php if ( $index == 0 ) { ?>
        image 1
    <?php } elseif ( $index == 1 ) { ?>
        image 2
    <?php } elseif ( $index == 2 ) { ?>
        image 3
    <?php } elseif ( $index == 3 ) { ?>
        image 4
    <?php } 
     endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If 2 separated Background images:

```html
<div class="d-container"><div class="diagonal diagonal--left" style="background-image: url(
 <?php
  if ( $course_zig_images ) :
   foreach ( $course_zig_images as $index => $course_zig_image ) :
    if ($index == 0 ) :
     echo $course_zig_image['url'];
    endif;
   endforeach;
  endif;
 ?>
 )"></div></div>
  
  
  <div class="d-container"><div class="diagonal diagonal--right" style="background-image: url(
 <?php
 if ( $course_zig_images ) :
  foreach ( $course_zig_images as $index => $course_zig_image ) :
   if ($index == 1 ) :
    echo $course_zig_image['url'];
   endif;
  endforeach;
 endif;
 ?>
 )"></div></div>
```